# Suppose $\ a^{n}=0_{R} $, for some positive integer n, prove that $\ a =0_{R} $

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

I was thinking something like this:

$\ a^{2}r-a=0_{R} $,
     $\ a(ar-1_{R})=0_{R} $

the only possible outcomes is that either: $\ ar = 1_{R}$ or that: $\ a = 0_{R}  $

Am I on the right way? Would appreciate if someone would point me in the right direction otherwise :)

Comment: your last argument is incorrect, since $R$ is not supposed to be a domain. Use induction on $n$ instead. For the induction step, if $n\geq 2$ and $a^{n+1}=0$, then multiply by a suitable $r$ to get...

Comment: In rings, the occurrences of $[a\ne 0\land b\ne 0\land ab=0]$ are very common. In fact, if you could say that in your ring that does not happen, then you wouldn't be needing the whole $[\forall a,\exists r, a^2r=a]$ thing.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assume the property "$ab=0$ implies $a=0$ or $b=0$".

Instead you may use the formula $a^2r=a$ to see this:

$$a^nr=a^{n-1}\\ a^{n-1}r=a^{n-2}\\ \vdots$$ Fill in the rest of the details on your own.